# Which Twitter API Library for Ruby do you recommend?

Tags: ruby, api, twitter

What is the best Twitter API Library for Ruby?

I want to do simple things like:

- search for specifics keywords for a date range
- start following people
- tweet messages

How can I do these things with the library you recommend?

Answer (score 6):

I've used both twitter and twitter4r and I slightly prefer [twitter](https://github.com/sferik/twitter). The latest release (0.7) supports twitter lists.

Answer (score 4):

Twitter maintains a [list of recommended libraries](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Libraries); [this gem](http://twitter.rubyforge.org/) works pretty well.

Comment: I've seen this list, what I'm asking is for someone who already used some of them and know the advantages of each one.